# Kali + Win 11 dual-boot install mounting issues

Tags: linux, windows, debian, multi-boot, kali-linux

So, i'm trying to install Kali alongside Win 11 on my 1TB NVMe drive and I encountered a weird issue, which has never happened to me before:

The Kali installer fails to mount my devices NVMe drive (Intel Optane(R) memory (32GB) coupled with a 1TB NVMe SSD).

Also mounting them manually does not work.
There is no further specification of the error in the console output, other than "an error occured"

I flashed a USB drive with the Kali-live ISO and shrinked my C:/ drive as the Kali multi-boot doc sais. I also launched the life Kali and tried to use gparted to create the neccessary partitions for the installation. Gparted doesn't show any partitions, just the whole drive with it's 986GB.

Is there a known error or a common solution for this issue?

###### EDIT 1:

I made the terminal spit out this

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop]
└─$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1 /home/kali/Desktop/drive_i_just_mounted             32 ⨯
mount: /home/kali/Desktop/drive_i_just_mounted: unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'.
```

###### EDIT 2:

I just tested installing Ubuntu 20.01 LTS, assuming its more automated and guided installation-procedure has a better chance of detecting my Windows partitions. But it also failed to find them.
Ubuntu recognizes both NVMe's, but not their partitions.

That poses the question, if it might be about the drive-type that is built into my laptop.

###### EDIT 3:

I just did the some tests on 4 differnt laptops with mostly the same setup as my first one I described the issue with.

And 3 of them (without Intel Optane and NVMe M.2) didn't have the partition recognition issue. The 4th one with NVMe and Optane had the same issue I described. Neither gparted, nor the Kali and Ubuntu installers recognized the partitions on my drive.

Comment: If you are just trying out Kali (unfriendly OS), run it as a virtual machine). Works better. Posted from my Kali 2021-4 VM

Comment: I am actually starting pen testing and coding in C0. And Kali is the best for pen, plus i can use gcc on it.

I know that Kali isnt the best for linux beginners, but at least I used Raspbian before XD

/posted from my live-USB Kali with a german keyboard and an english layout, so i know that z and y are swapped but i have no idea where all the symbols are

Comment: Is your drive a part of a raid cluster? Then use the cluster-device and not the physical device.

Comment: I have no idea. It's built in into a HP Spectre x360 notebook. It should not be part of a RAID. Or is it? I don't know how that works.
I have an Intel Optane(R) memory (32GB) coupled with a 1TB NVMe SSD. Hope that info helps. I'm also updating my post with that info.

Comment: As long as this issue persists, I'm gonna run a VM on VirtualBox for Kali, which is the less comfy option, but better than nothing.

Comment: *It should not be part of a RAID* but it is as long as you use the factory setup for Optane.

Comment: I see. How do I change this? / Should I change this? and would it help
Sorry for potentially stupid questions, i'm usually programming computers and when I work with hardware it's space related stuff, no RAIDs or GPUs included XD
I know what a RAID is, but have no idea how it might affect my Linux installation. I never did multiboot before btw

Comment: It affects because neither the UEFI "RAID" nor the Intel RST drive modes are (yet) compatible. The supported mode is AHCI. And, of course, AHCI support must be installed in Windows prior to changing the mode to finally enable the installation a Linux distro in dual-boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you could write that as an answer. If the RAID and RST modes are not supported, then my problem ist... well... solved in a way XD

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for it, you just need to turn of optane while installing linux and switch to achi because linux does not support the other one. After this you will not be abe to boot on windows and be aware that you should install it again or startup repair it if you want to boot in windows again just change achi on rst and windows will boot but linux will not, all in all just go on AMD

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was playing with the thought of turning off Optane in favor of Linux but I am not sure about it yet 

Comment: i know man its a hard decision but i see no other way, unless u have extra money to buy 2nd hard drive, when i had this issue(on predator 300) i have read some articles saying if u install linux on other drive separately it may work but i am not sure about it just try and turn off optane (its easy to turn on again) and change bios settings